# Как сделать правильную выборку строк в Oracle аналогично limit и offset в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется такой запрос

```
select * from
 (select * from
  (select a.*, rownum rnum from
   (select * from dimax)a)
 where rownum <= 5)
where rnum > 2
```

Таблица на месте dimax всегда разная, то есть у меня есть сто таблиц и их столбцы отличаются и не известно какую таблицу я буду использоваться в запросе.
Все бы работало хорошо, но одна из таблиц может совпадать с псевдонимом rownum и тогда запрос не выполнится.
Как обойти эту проблему и выбирать нужные строки в неизвестной таблице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используется Oracle 12 и выше, то можно использовать [OFFSET и FETCH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

```
SELECT *
FROM dimax
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

`ORDER BY` нужен иначе порядок строк будет произвольным.

В более старых версиях можно делать так:

```
select *
  from (select d.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from dimax d)
 where rn between 3 and 5
 order by rn;
```

Этот запрос принципиально не отличается от Вашего и если в `dimax` будет столбец `rn`, то запрос не сработает. Не знаю как это можно обойти. Как вариант, можно добавить какую-то предобработку, либо просто выбрать имя, которое не встречается ни в одной из таблиц:

```
select *
  from (select d.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn___ from dimax d)
 where rn___ between 3 and 5
 order by rn___;
```

Посмотрите другие варианты в похожем вопросе на английском: [Paging with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241622)

Comment: В общем нужно ждать когда Oracle сделает человеческий limit и offset, а так решением вижу задать псевдоним который с вероятностью 99.999999% не будет использоваться в имени колонки